# Not showing me the "wrong password provided for that user" or "no user found for that email" dialog box

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I have used Firebase to create a login method, but the "`wrong password provided for that user`" or "`no user found for that email`" dialog box doesn't appear, even when it is supposed to. But even though the alert doesn't appear, the app is not getting signed in though. So the method is working as it is supposed to I guess, just that the dialog box is not appearing. Why could it be?

PS: I'm super new to Flutter. So it would be helpful if someone explained the issue in laymans term

Edit - Instead of FirebaseAuthException catch(e), I tried changing it to catch(e) and displayed a general error message like 'Error logging in. Incorrect email or password. It is working perfectly now

But when I tried doing the same for the register user screen:

```
on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      dialogueBox(context, e.toString());
}
```

to

```
catch (e) {
        dialogueBox(context, 'Error creating account. The email entered could already be in use');
}
```

it is not working here though. What could be the reason?

Link for reference:
https://github.com/ahkharsha/PregaCare/blob/main/lib/wife_register_screen.dart

Comment: What happens when you log the value of `e.code` just before you use it?  Does it contain the value you expect?

Comment: Uh im kinda new to flutter. how do I 'log' the value of e.code? Is it the same as just printing it?

Comment: I'm sure a web search for "how to log a value in flutter" will be of help. On Stack Overflow, it's expected that your post shows that you put some effort into debugging it.  That includes learning how to log vales and do step through debugging.

Answer (score 0):

A relatively recent security change for Firebase is that it will no longer leak whether or not a username exists.  Both of your desired error messages leak that information, so I presume you're just getting some sort of general "bad login" error instead.  Perhaps you're copying this from an old tutorial made before the change?

Comment: Yes, I understood the previous problem now. Instead of FirebaseAuthException catch(e), I tried changing it to catch(e), and displayed a general error message like 'Error logging in. Incorrect email or password'. It is working perfectly now But when I tried doing the same for the register user screen: 
`on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) { dialogueBox(context, e.toString()); }`

to

`catch (e) { 
    dialogueBox(context, 'Error creating account. The email entered could already be in use');
}`

it is not working here. What could be the reason? I have modified it in my question post now